# How to change a file name of a google form bu Apps script

Tags: forms

For a `google spreadsheet` it is easy to change the filename by using this script:

```
var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Idfile);
file.rename("new name");
```

Logical to me for change file name of a form:

```
var form = FormApp.openById(Idform);
form.rename("new name");
```

*However this does not work!*

Who knows the solution to change a filename of a `google form` by using apps script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this method?

```
DriveApp.getFileById(id).setName("new name");
```

This method can also rename Spreadsheet.

#### Reference :

- [setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setName(String))

Comment: @user3887038 Welcome. Thank you, too.

Comment: how to wait for this function to end?

Comment: @Ali Samie About your question of `how to wait for this function to end?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: my question is that is there anyway to wait for the setName function to change name and change browser tab name like how its done in JS promises...?

Comment: @Ali Samie About your question of `my question is that is there anyway to wait for the setName function to change name and change browser tab name like how its done in JS promises...?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?