# How can i modify the name to an uploaded google form file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I`m trying to use the bellow script code to modify the name to an attachment from google form using another text and i receive the following error:

"ReferenceError: nameColumn is not defined at rename(Code:26:22)"

What i`m doing wrong?

```
var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
// Notice the second 2, this is to avoid the Timestamp Column
var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2,2, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);

// Replace with your values (Column A=1, B=2, etc...)
var nameColumn = 2; // B
var urlColumn = 3; // C

// Calculating index for array
nameColumn -= 2;
urlColumn -= 2;
}
function last() {
  var lastRowContents=sheet.getRange(lastRow,2,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  rename(lastRowContents);
}
function rename(row) {

  // Using the first field, Name (Index 0 becuse of the array, calculated above)
  // ** Even though the Name field is the second column, we see it as the first one since 
  //    we ignored the timestamp column in the searchRange **
  var userName = row[nameColumn];
  var url = row[urlColumn];

  // Retrieve the ID from the URL
  var Id = url.split('=')[1];

  // Adapt this newFileName to your needs
  var newFileName = userName;

  // Get the file and rename it
  DriveApp.getFileById(Id).setName(newFileName);
  Logger.log("Renamed file with ID " + Id + " to " + newFileName);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the description of forms (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item) I did not find any access to attachments. I created a form with one question and inserted an image. I ran this code to see if the script had access to the image. The script only found one item - the unnamed question.

```
function exploreFormItems() {
  const formId = '1EuPT6qNHfAWkbZhnlEpi1WPgMaIVPZDybM8h86jX3gg';
  let form = FormApp.openById(formId);
  let itemArr = form.getItems();
  let idx = 0;
  itemArr.forEach (function(item) {
    console.log ('idx     : ', idx );
    console.log ('   id   : ', item.getId() );
    console.log ('   index: ', item.getIndex() );
    console.log ('   title: ', item.getTitle() );
    console.log ('   type : ', item.getType() );
    console.log ('   help : ', item.getHelpText() );
    ++idx;
  }  );
}
```

If you are trying to rename the form itself I found this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375841/how-to-change-a-file-name-of-a-google-form-bu-apps-script#:~:text=For%20a%20google%20spreadsheet%20it,rename(%22new%20name%22)%3B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375841/how-to-change-a-file-name-of-a-google-form-bu-apps-script#:%7E:text=For%20a%20google%20spreadsheet%20it,rename(%22new%20name%22)%3B)

Comment: I tried to modify the name of the image with that script after it was saved on drive. On Submit, the form creates a new line in the sheet file with 3 rows: Timestamp, NAME, Picture URL(it will be more but after i see how this works). I need, after Submit, the name of the picture, wich i have the URL, to be NAME. Can you help me to do it?

Comment: The script does not see the attached image.

Comment: We can not find any solutions?